# How to one column full result and max of that column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Max(c.vendor_id),c.vendors_id FROM (SELECT distinct a.vendor_id FROM service_master a,products b,vendors v,`vendor_addresses` ad WHERE a.cat_id= 242 AND a.service_id = b.s_sid AND a.is_active =1 AND b.isproductactive = 1 AND v.vendorid = a.vendor_id AND ad.vendorchild_id = a.vendor_id AND v.isvendoractive = 1 LIMIT 10) c ORDER BY c.vendor_id
```

Questions:
1)I want full result in vendor_id column
2)Max(vendor_id)result

How to get result in single query?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. But please try this.

```
select t1.id,t2.id
from detail t1
left join(
    select max(id) as id 
    from detail
) t2 on 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, ( select max(id) from detail internal_detail 
where detail.id = internal_detail.id ) as max from detail
```